# Auto fill city after typing in zip code

Tags: php, json, autofill, zipcode, city

I need to auto fill fill the CITY: form when typing in the zip code,
it says "undefiened variable: array on line.." where value="< ? php $array['navn']  ">

can someone help ?

http://i62.tinypic.com/hv5fkl.jpg

```
<div id="search">
                        <form name="input" action="" method="get">
                            POST:<input type="text" name="postcode"><br><br>
                            City:<input type="text" name="navn" value="<?php $array['navn'] ?>"><br><br>
                            <input type="submit" value="search">
                        </form> 
                    </div>


                    </div>

                   <?php
                        if(isset($_GET['postcode'])){


                        $postcode = $_GET['postcode'];

                        $content = file_get_contents('http://oiorest.dk/danmark/postdistrikter/'. $postcode . '.json');

                        $array = json_decode($content, true);


                            echo $array['navn'];
                            echo "<br>";


                        }
                    ?>
```

Comment: use `$array[$_GET['navn']];` to get the value

Comment: In my input form ? and will it help to autofill ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to always initialize variables. What happens is that you're trying to access a variable that hasn't been initialized yet.

```
<?php

$city = ''; // initialize containers
$postcode = '';

if(isset($_GET['postcode'])){
    $postcode = $_GET['postcode'];
    $content = file_get_contents('http://oiorest.dk/danmark/postdistrikter/'. $postcode . '.json');
    $array = json_decode($content, true);
    // when the request is made, then assign
    $city = $array['navn'];
}

?>

<!-- so that when you echo, you'll never worry about undefined indices -->
<div id="search">
    <form name="input" action="" method="get">
    POST:<input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>"><br><br>
    City:<input type="text" name="navn" value="<?php echo $city; ?>"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="search">
    </form>
</div>
```

In this answer, what happens is that, upon first load (no json request yet), the values are empty but they are declared on top.

When you submit the form, then that variable assignment happens and substitutes the values into that container.

[**Simple Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/B6tBOB)

Comment: Niceee, thank you !

the only thing is that it not ( auto fill ) the city form when typing the zip code

Comment: @IPastuhI what do you mean autofill? thats the browsers job

Comment: I mean that when i type in the zip code for example 5250 and without clicking on the search button it finds the city name

Comment: @IPastuhI well thats not autofill, thats like autocomplete behavior, and you need some jquery autocomplete ajax to do just that. well thats just for another question

Comment: understood, which one is best for this job ? and could you help me with that so I can mark your answer as correct ?

Comment: @IPastuhI actually taking this simple route is okay, in using that ajax, its a long way to go, you need to understand first how to use jquery and implementing ajax, calling php script and stuff. return json and stuff.

Comment: I really need help with that

Comment: @IPastuhI well you need to learn how to use jquery first. and thats a boat load of codes and too broad for scope of stackoverflow. You need to learn each technology first. its not good that i write up like a whole tutorial in here that works but you won't understand how it got working